# Chrome/Webkit hover issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I've encountered this weird bug with the hover effect in Chrome 46.

There's a list of items and only some of them should highlight when hovered over, but the result is not as expected.
Furthermore, when opening debug and enabling the hover effect on the element that should highlight, it starts working fine afterwards.

It seems like the second hover rule is not triggering for some elements

```
ul.listings li.listing:hover {
  border-color: #ccc;
}

ul.listings li.listing:hover div.special {
  color: red!important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/celsum/nLrveyfs/

It works fine in Firefox 42 and IE 10.

Also, a screenshot of what's happening in case it's a non-issue for others: http://snag.gy/oHG9v.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the fact that your `div.special` is of different height than `li.listing`. So when you hover only on the word 'Special', the color changes to red and it does not change to red when you hover on the list containing `div.special`(This is the problem which I found in Chrome 47). So for this, I have added some changes to your CSS:

```
div.special{
  height:60px;
} 

ul.listings li.listing div.special:hover{
  color: red!important;
}
```

Also here is an [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLrveyfs/7/) for the same.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you just want to change the style of the `div.special` when `li.listing` is hovered then change your CSS like this:

```
ul.listings li.listing div.image div.special:hover{
  color: red!important;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLrveyfs/9/) for the same.

Comment: The intent is to change the style of div.special when li.listing is hovered and not when div.special is. While your suggestion might work in some cases, in this situation div.special is not meant to be the same size as li.listing

Comment: Updated the code. Please check and let me know if it helped.